# Parse Javascript array to bootstrap div and rows

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want to load data from api and then parse it into bootstrap rows. I have an array finalData which contains 15 strings, I need to parse it to create a bootstrap rows/cards

I am trying this but first time number of elements are coming up to be 5 as the index starts from 0. What additional condition do I need to use?

```
let finalData = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","i"];

finalData.forEach((element, index) => {

        index == 0 ? mhtml += `<div class="row">` : null;
        mhtml += `<div class="col-sm-3">
                    finalData[index]
                </div>`;
        index != 0 && index % 4 == 0 ? mhtml += `</div><div class="row">` : null;
    });
```

This is giving me following result: **I don't need 5 element in first row I need 4 in all.**

```
<div class="row>
a
b
c
d
e
</div>
<div class="row>
f
g
h
i
</div>
<div class="row>
j
k
l
m
</div>
<div class="row>
n
i
</div>
<div class="row>
```

I need result to be:

```
<div class="row>
a
b
c
d
</div>
<div class="row>
e
f
g
h
</div>
<div class="row>
i
j
k
l
</div>
<div class="row>
m
n
i
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you're checking when modulo 4 is zero, but this will be your 5th element. try using (index + 1) % 4 instead

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the results fit the index - your first pass through is grabbing index values 0,1,2,3,4 which is 5 rows. Your second pass is grabbing 5 6, 7, 8 which fits your requirements. You just need to check for (index + 1) % 4

```
index != 0 && ((index + 1) % 4) == 0 ? mhtml += `</div><div class="row">` : null;
```